# WHMCS Hook - foreach error

Tags: foreach, smarty, hook, whmcs

I'm trying to make a hook and I got an issue with a foreach function.

I got the following error, but I'm using the smarty foreach function from http://docs.whmcs.com/Email_Templates.

```
// Call WHMCS API - send admin email 
$command = "sendadminemail"; 
$adminuser = "admin"; 
$values["customsubject"] = "Daily Cron Report"; 
$values["custommessage"] = "Domains Report<br>"; 
$values["custommessage"] .= "--------------------<br>"; 
$values["custommessage"] .= "{$active_domains_count} Active Domains<br>{$expired_domains_count} Expired Domains<br>"; 
$values["custommessage"] .= "--------------------<br>"; 
$values["custommessage"] .= "Expired Domains"; 
$values["custommessage"] .= "{foreach from=$expired_domains item=expireddomains}-{$expireddomains.domain}<br>{/foreach}"; 
$values["customvars"] = array("active_domains_count" => $active_domains_count, "expired_domains_count" => $expired_domains_count, "expired_domains" => $expired_domains); 
$values["type"] = "system"; 

$results = localAPI($command, $values, $adminuser);
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '}' in
>   /includes/hooks/dailycron.php on line 24

Any suggestions ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use php -l to debug sintax errors, your issue was in line 11, closing the string with single quotes instead of double ones fixed it.

```
<?php
// Call WHMCS API - send admin email
$command = "sendadminemail";
$adminuser = "admin";
$values["customsubject"] = "Daily Cron Report";
$values["custommessage"] = "Domains Report<br>";
$values["custommessage"] .= "--------------------<br>";
$values["custommessage"] .= "{$active_domains_count} Active Domains<br>{$expired_domains_count} Expired Domains<br>";
$values["custommessage"] .= "--------------------<br>";
$values["custommessage"] .= "Expired Domains";
$values["custommessage"] .= '{foreach from=$expired_domains item=expireddomains}-{$expireddomains.domain}<br>{/foreach}';
$values["customvars"] = array("active_domains_count" => $active_domains_count, "expired_domains_count" => $expired_domains_count, "expired_domains" => $expired_domains);
$values["type"] = "system";

$results = localAPI($command, $values, $adminuser);
```

Comment: I fixed this with foreach outside the email HTML. Its working. Smarty foreach is not working